# Shortcut for changing package name declaration in java

Tags: java, eclipse

We have a simple java project in eclipse and we have migrated package name for an already existing source code. Is there a shortcut for changing package name declarations while you are inside the code editor

Comment: and which particular editor might this be?

Comment: have you trie to refrator the package ?

Comment: @anirvan The post has the [eclipse] tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the package name, and use `Refactor -> Rename` (<kbd>Shift+Alt+R</kbd>) to open the Rename Package dialog

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring is the best way, however be wary of changing package names if your source is under version control. I've had all sorts of conflict, update issues with changing package names because of the sequence of commits done (to SVN). It does work, just can be tricky to get everything commited correctly and the repository and working directory correctly in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Just select your package and press-hold the Alt-Shift-R keys. Alternatively, you can select your package, right click it and select Refactor -> Rename.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the structure of a project, eclipse prompts you to update the references. If you allow eclipse, it will do it automatically. Now, you can perform a Find & Replace operation to manually update you package names.